# AssetBundle returns null after upgrading unity version to Unity2017.1.0f3

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, assetbundle

All my assetbundle are working in my previous version of Unity 5.6.1f1 (64-bit). But after upgrading to Unity2017.1.0f3, my LoadFromCacheOrDownload returns null. This is for android build.

How I load the assetbundle:

```
WWW _www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload(Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "test"), 0);
```

And this is how I create my assetBundle:

```
Object[] selectedAssets = Selection.GetFiltered(typeof(Object), SelectionMode.DeepAssets);
BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundle(Selection.activeObject, selectedAssets, bundlePath, BuildAssetBundleOptions.CollectDependencies | BuildAssetBundleOptions.CompleteAssets, BuildTarget.Android);
```